# Python: Search in dict embedded in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tumblr

Sorry for very badly english.
Hello. How i can get url from this list?

```
[{u'highlighted': [], u'image_permalink': u'http://bluebeetlezar.tumblr.com/image/101630187766', u'reblog_key': u'RWjDEE41', u'format': u'html', u'timestamp': 1414973540, u'note_count': 0, u'tags': [u'train', u'railway', u'station', u'silent', u'morning'], u'photos': [{u'caption': u'', u'original_size': {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, u'alt_sizes': [{u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_500.jpg', u'width': 500, u'height': 500}, {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_400.jpg', u'width': 400, u'height': 400}, {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_250.jpg', u'width': 250, u'height': 250}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_100.jpg', u'width': 100, u'height': 100}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_75sq.jpg', u'width': 75, u'height': 75}]}], u'id': 101630187766, u'post_url': u'http://bluebeetlezar.tumblr.com/post/101630187766/stasiun-gondangdia-in-the-morniiiiinnngg', u'caption': u'<p>Stasiun Gondangdia in the morniiiiinnngg :) #railway #station #train #morning #silent</p>', u'state': u'published', u'short_url': u'http://tmblr.co/Z2EiHt1UfePZs', u'date': u'2014-11-03 00:12:20 GMT', u'link_url': u'http://instagram.com/p/u6sFevMNJ2/', u'type': u'photo', u'slug': u'stasiun-gondangdia-in-the-morniiiiinnngg', u'blog_name': u'bluebeetlezar'}]
```

I wanna use .get, but this data - list. How i can extract url anoter way? Or list -> dict? (dict() doesnt work or i stupid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'    your_list[0]['image_permalink'] # -> http://bluebeetlezar.tumblr.com/image/101630187766

```
your_list[0]['photos'][0]['original_size']["url"] # -> http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg
```

You only have a single element inside the list which is a dict, use `your_list[0]` to access it then use the keys to get whatever url you need.

```
In [27]: your_list[0]['photos'][0]['original_size']['url']
Out[27]: 'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg'
```

Comment: I get permalink, but i cant get {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg'

Comment: I added the output I get running the code on the list in your question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things you could try:

```
L = [{u'highlighted': [], u'image_permalink': u'http://bluebeetlezar.tumblr.com/image/101630187766', u'reblog_key': u'RWjDEE41', u'format': u'html', u'timestamp': 1414973540, u'note_count': 0, u'tags': [u'train', u'railway', u'station', u'silent', u'morning'], u'photos': [{u'caption': u'', u'original_size': {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, u'alt_sizes': [{u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_1280.jpg', u'width': 640, u'height': 640}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_500.jpg', u'width': 500, u'height': 500}, {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_400.jpg', u'width': 400, u'height': 400}, {u'url': u'http://38.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_250.jpg', u'width': 250, u'height': 250}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_100.jpg', u'width': 100, u'height': 100}, {u'url': u'http://33.media.tumblr.com/aa3018b3d8b147dc49e4b407b62f2b94/tumblr_nefsklMDSb1s385n2o1_75sq.jpg', u'width': 75, u'height': 75}]}], u'id': 101630187766, u'post_url': u'http://bluebeetlezar.tumblr.com/post/101630187766/stasiun-gondangdia-in-the-morniiiiinnngg', u'caption': u'<p>Stasiun Gondangdia in the morniiiiinnngg :) #railway #station #train #morning #silent</p>', u'state': u'published', u'short_url': u'http://tmblr.co/Z2EiHt1UfePZs', u'date': u'2014-11-03 00:12:20 GMT', u'link_url': u'http://instagram.com/p/u6sFevMNJ2/', u'type': u'photo', u'slug': u'stasiun-gondangdia-in-the-morniiiiinnngg', u'blog_name': u'bluebeetlezar'}]

def printUrls(L):
    whitelist = set(["u'image_permalink", "url"])
    for d in L:
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for k in d:
                if k in whitelist:
                    print(d[k])
                    continue

        if isinstance(d, list):
            printUrls(d)
```

Or:

```
def printUrls(L):
    for d in L:
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for _k,v in d.items():
                if v.startswith('http'):
                    print(v)
                    continue

        if isinstance(d, list):
            printUrls(d)
```